# Use of BIRT (.rptlibrary) on Maven project

Tags: java, maven, birt

I wanted to know where I had to place my file **BirtReportEngine** in my structure Maven project ?

should I create a folder under `src/main/ressources`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate BIRT report viewer,try this step by step.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-birt-viewer-java-webapps/index.html
Hope this may help you.